# Displaying error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

code displaying error in controller on line 8,9,10,11 that is trying to get property of non-object.
//checked all column names and table name.

my model is

```
public function getEducationDetail($educationID) {
    $this->db->select('qual_id,pass_year,institute,percentage,emp_id');
    $this->db->from('emp_edu');
    $this->db->where('edu_id', $educationID);
    $this->db->where('del_flag', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query->result();
    else:
        return 0;
    endif;
}
```

and my controller is

```
 public function getEducationDetail() {

    $this->load->model('mod_admin');
    if (isset($_GET['param'])):
        $educationID = $this->input->get('param');
        $result = $this->mod_admin->getEducationDetail($educationID);
        $jsonArr = array(
            'qualificationID' => $result->qual_id,
            'passOut' => $result->pass_out,
            'institute' => $result->institute,
            'percentage' => $result->percentage
        );
    endif;
    $json = json_encode(array('result' => $jsonArr));
    echo $json;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model returns single row `$query->row()` then

```
$result = $this->mod_admin->getEducationDetail($educationID);
if (!empty($result)) {
    $jsonArr = array(
        'qualificationID' => $result->qual_id,
        'passOut' => $result->pass_out,
        'institute' => $result->institute,
        'percentage' => $result->percentage
    );
}
```

If it returns multi rows `$query->result()` then

```
$results = $this->mod_admin->getEducationDetail($educationID);

$jsonArr = array();

if (!empty($results)) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $jsonArr[] = array(
            'qualificationID' => $result->qual_id,
            'passOut' => $result->pass_out,
            'institute' => $result->institute,
            'percentage' => $result->percentage
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

return `$query->result()` it will give multi dimensional array. I think you will get a single row as result. 
change it as `return $query->row()`

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public function getEducationDetail($educationID) {
    $this->db->select('qual_id,pass_year,institute,percentage,emp_id');
    $this->db->where('edu_id', $educationID);
    $this->db->where('del_flag', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get('emp_edu');

       return $query->row();

}
```

Controller

```
public function getEducationDetail() {

$this->load->model('mod_admin');
if (isset($_GET['param'])):
    $educationID = $this->input->get('param');
    $result = $this->mod_admin->getEducationDetail($educationID);
if($result){
    $jsonArr = array(
        'qualificationID' => $result->qual_id,
        'passOut' => $result->pass_out,
        'institute' => $result->institute,
        'percentage' => $result->percentage
    );
$json = json_encode(array('result' => $jsonArr));
echo $json;
endif;
   }
}
```